# If I use modernizr do i have to write additional code to fallbacks work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr

Let's say I am using modernizr for text shadows and in IE 9 it doesn't work.  Do i simply have to include the js file or write additional code to work in conformity with modernizr?

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr doesn't do anything if it doesn't work; it simply returns `false` for that check.

If you want it to work, you need to pick a fallback yourself.

You can use `Modernizr.load()` to easily load it only if a feature is not supported.

Comment: so i do have to write something if the browser doesn't support the funciton?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to do something more. Modernizr just gives a `true` or `false` response to say whether a feature is supported or not. You still have responsibility to do something in response to the `false`.

That might be loading a polyfill script (Modernizr provides [a big list of them you could try](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)) or giving some alternative functionality, or just a message telling the user they need a better browser. How you handle it is up to you.

Modernizr doesn't fix the browser up for you; it's just the tool that gives you the ability to know what needs fixing.